# Wrong execution order in objective C code

Tags: objective-c, ios6, performselector

I have following code in my iOS app:

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self performSelector: @selector(generateDataForDates:) withObject:paramArray afterDelay:0.1];
});

return self.dataArray;
```

App is executing return statement first and then above 'performselector' which is causing data  inconsistencies. 
Do anyone has any clue? I need to execute performselector first and then return statement.

Answer (score 0):

`performSelector:withObject:afterDelay:` will schedule the selector to be performed after the delay and will not wait until the selector is performed. It will return immediately.

This will work, but why would you even dispatch this block?

```
[UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{
    [self generateDataForDates:paramArray];
});

return self.dataArray;
```

Comment: networkActivityIndicator will not show up in new view if delay is zero. It is the only reason for using delay in performselector.

Comment: You can't do this with waiting for the `generateDataForDates:` to finish in the same method. You will have call an extra method after a delay that will do the `generateDataForDates` and handle the data when finished.

Comment: It is not changing anything. Actually problem is with some library we are using - it is forcing an event to execute return statement first and then call the performselector. So I was asking if something could be done so that performselector is the first statement to get executed and then return statement.

Comment: You will have to rap that code so that it can be executed Async there  is not other way to do it.

Comment: Anyways thanks rckoenes. Do you have any other suggestion? Or someone other in the community could help?